# printfn in pipeline

Tags: f#, pipeline

So I have a function SolveEquasion that returns a pair float*float[]. What is the best way to print the number and the array and continue working with the array? I made the following code but it seems there is a better way

> ```
> ...
> |> SolveEquasion
> |> (fun (det, solution) -> printfn "Determinant = %f\nSolution = %A" det (Array.toList solution), solution )
> |> snd
> ```

Comment: When you say "continue working with the array" do you mean pipe it to other functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one thing you can skip the use of `snd` by returning a single value rather than a tuple from the previous function:

```
...
|> SolveEquasion
|> (fun (det, solution) -> 
        printfn "Determinant = %f\nSolution = %A" det (Array.toList solution) 
        solution )
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your solution can improved if you want to do this in a pipeline. Another approach is to use a `let` binding, along with splitting up the pipelined operations, to avoid having a function that acts like the love child of `map` and `iter`.

```
let (det, solution) = SolveEquasion
printfn "Determinant = %f\nSolution = %A" det (Array.toList solution)
//do something else with solution
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the original solution is fine, and we can improve its clarity by giving your anonymous function the name I've seen it given in some other libraries based around pipelining higher-order functions:  *tap*.

```
let tap f x =
    f x
    x

(1.0, [| 2.0; 3.0 |])
|> tap (fun (s, a) -> printfn "%A %A" s a)
|> snd
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use Daniel's approach and just assign the value you want to print to a symbol using `let`. Alternatively, you could define a variant of `printf` that takes some arguments and returns one of them. I'm not sure if there is a general scheme how this should be done - for your example it would take a two-element tuple:

```
let mprintf fmt (a, b) = 
  Printf.kprintf (fun s -> printf "%s" s; (a, b)) fmt a b
```

Then you can write:

```
...  
|> SolveEquasion  
|> mprintfn "Determinant = %f\nSolution = %A"
|> snd |> // ... more stuff with solution
```